# Ajax POST error interno 500

Tags: php, ajax

Al ejecutar el ajax arroja el error POST 500. El php arroja el problema si defino `$columna= $_POST['columna'];` pero si yo defino por prueba `$columna='marca';` el PHP funciona correctamente y envia la informacion a ajax de forma correcta. Por lo que supongo que el problema esta en lo que envia ajax y como lo recibe PHP.

```
function traer( id )
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '../server/info.php',
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: { id: id },
        type: 'POST',
        success: (data) =>{
            $( "#" + id ).html( data );
        },
        error: function(){
            alert( "Error con el servidor" );
        } 
    })
}

document.getElementById("marca").onclick=function(event){traer("marca");};
```

Comment: ¿Y qué tal si pones la parte del PHP que te está dando el error ? ¿Qué imprime `echo $_POST['columna'];`?

Comment: La respuesta es null

Comment: Para darte una respuesta más precisa es necesario que coloques en la pregunta la parte de donde sacas el valor que quieres enviar por `$_POST['columna'];`. Sea si lo envías desde un formulario o de otra parte. Así mismo, sería útil que pongas la parte PHP donde intentas recuperar ese valor. Si el valor está en un formulario, debes usar lo que diga en la etiqueta `name` del input que quieres recuperar. Es decir, debería llamarse `columna` en este caso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si quieres recibir parametro del lado del servidor tienes que enviarlo con el mismo nombre que espera en PHP.

En el ajax tienes:

```
 $.ajax({
   data: {id: id}
   //..
 });
```

Pero en php esperas `$_POST['columna'];`.

Por lo que deberia de ser:

```
 $.ajax({
   data: {columna: id}
   //..
 });
```

Recuerda que puedes enviar cuanto parametros quieras:

```
 $.ajax({
   data: {columna: id, nombre__ : "Einer", sitio: "www.google.com" }
   //..
 });
```

Y en el php:

```
$sitio = $_POST["sitio"];
$column = $_POST["columna"];
$nombre = $_POST["nombre__"];
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta! Un pequeño aporte: si además querés evitar que salten errores cuando algún parámetro no es enviado podés hacer `$sitio = (isset($_POST["sitio"])) ?
 $_POST["sitio"] : null;` ya que si falta el parámetro van a saltar excepciones y se te va a armar lío! Saludos!

Comment: Tienes razon pero ahora veo que lo que recibe php es un valor null.

Comment: Cual valor es el que te llega como null?

Comment: $columna = $_POST["columna"]; su valor es null

Comment: Verifica que la variable `id` que le pasas como parametro no sea null

Comment: la variable id si tiene valor lo cheque en la función error del ajax con alert(id); pero lo que recibe $columna = $_POST["columna"]; es null.

Answer (score 0):

El error era ocasionado por  cache: false, processData: false, contentType: false, simplemente hay que eliminarlos. Ademas se cambia el valor de data por data: "columna="+id haciendo que en PHP sea $_POST['columna']  .

```
function traer(id) {
 $.ajax({
   url: '../server/info.php',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: "columna="+id,
   type: 'POST',
   success:function(data) {
     $("#" + id).html(data);

   },
   error: function(){
     alert( "Error con el servidor" );
   }
 });
```

};

```
document.getElementById("marca").addEventListener("click", traer("marca"));
```